# Validação Regex de data com 2/2/4 caracteres

Tags: javascript, regex, data, validação

Buscando bastante, achei algumas explicações sobre como validar data com Regex porém meu conhecimento em regex é um pouco limitado ainda.

Com algumas modificações nas explicações que achei, cheguei a um objeto bacana porém não entendi ao certo onde modifico para ele aceitar apenas o formato `DD/MM/AAAA` pois o que tenho aceita tanto este formato mas também aceita os formatos `D/M/AA` ou `DD/M/AA` ou `D/MM/AAAA` ou tanto faz.

Ou seja, eu queria validar apenas o formato com a quantidade de caracteres a seguir `2/2/4` ou `DD(2 números)/MM(2 números)/AAAA(4 Números)`

No caso ele aceita `1|2 / 1|2 / 2|4` caracteres. Como eu faria para no exemplo https://regexr.com/4b1eb | https://regex101.com/r/cRGVvH/1 poder aceitar apenas o formato `2/2/4` caracteres ou `DD/MM/AAAA` ou `29/02/2016` e não `29/2/16`.

Esta expressão também valida ano bissexto e meses que não possuem 31 dias, e funciona bem neste quesito o que não queria mudar pois funciona legal neste ponto de validar ano bissexto e meses sem 31 dias

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

E no caso, eu posso também aceitar os caracteres `/` ou `-` ou `.` como divisor que não tem nenhum problema neste ponto também que no caso é este trecho `(\/|-|\.)` que se repete algumas vezes na expressão onde se eu quizer limitar a `/` basta eu fazer `(\/)` que ele aceita apenas barra, mas eu poderia também aceitar `nada` como divizor fazendo isso `(\/|-|\.|)` só não sei se é a melhor forma de aceitar `nada` como divisor.

Ou seja, a espressão é funcional, mesmo sendo enorme ela é funcional, ao menos aparenta ser, só queria mesmo não permitir menos que 2 números para Dia, 2 números para Mês e 4 números para Ano, tudo bem que uma espressão menor que continue validando ano bissexto e meses sem 31 dias ajudaria mas não posso utilizar o javascript em sí, precisa ser regex.

Este exemplo dado como possível solução por [@hkotsubo](https://regex101.com/r/cRGVvH/1)

```
(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[0-1])(\/|\-|\.|)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\2\d{4}
```

Onde modifiquei de acordo com sua orientação e adicionei o `nada` como divisor é bem legal, só vou ver como coloco os validadores de bissexto e meses sem 31 dias, ou seja, ver se é possível mesclar uma na outra, o nada eu inclui neste trecho `(\/|\-|\.|)` se outra forma for melhor, também aceito a explicação

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sinceramente, esta regex que você está usando, na minha opinião, não é nada prática e eu evitaria usar em qualquer sistema em produção. Basta ver a dificuldade que você está tendo para entendê-la e modificá-la. Pense se realmente vale a pena.

Esta regex faz validações que são muito mais fáceis de se fazer fora dela, como verificar se um ano é bissexto (e com isso saber se fevereiro deve ter 28 ou 29 dias), além de verificar meses com 30 ou 31 dias. Mas para que tudo isso, se é muito mais simples verificar fora dela? Regex processa texto, mesmo dígitos como `1` ou `2` são tratados como meros caracteres, e qualquer cálculo matemático é muito mais fácil de ser feito fora da regex.

Dito isso, se você recebe uma string e quer verificar se ela corresponde a uma data no formato 'dd/mm/aaaa', não precisa usar uma super-regex-complicada-que-faz-tudo.

Você pode usar uma regex mais simples, **apenas** para validar o formato "dois dígitos, barra, dois dígitos, barra, quatro dígitos" e depois validar esses valores separadamente:

```js
let match = /^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/.exec('20/10/2018');
if (match) {
    let dia = parseInt(match[1]);
    let mes = parseInt(match[2]);
    let ano = parseInt(match[3]);

    let d = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia);
    let dataValida = d.getFullYear() == ano
                     && d.getMonth() + 1 == mes
                     && d.getDate() == dia;
    console.log(dataValida); // true
} else {
    console.log('string não está no formato dd/mm/aaaa, ou não é uma data');
}
```

A regex só serve para verificar se a string possui exatamente dois dígitos, barra, mais dois dígitos, barra, mais 4 dígitos. Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` significam, respectivamente, o início e fim da string, garantindo assim que a string só tem o que está na regex.

Usando `\d{2}` e `\d{4}` eu garanto as quantidades corretas de dígitos, e caso a regex retorne um *match*, eu posso transformar os respectivos valores em números, usando [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Isso é possível porque cada número está entre parênteses na regex, e isso forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (com isso eu posso obter cada grupo usando `match[numero_do_grupo]`).

O [construtor de `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) recebe o ano, mês e dia, com o cuidado de subtrair 1 do mês, já que para esta classe janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc.

O problema é que essa classe aceita valores inválidos, como mês 13, dia 32, etc, e faz alguns ajustes no resultado final (por exemplo, se tentar criar 32 de janeiro, o resultado é 1 de fevereiro). Por isso, para saber se os valores do dia, mês e ano são válidos, basta compará-los com o `Date` criado. Se não houve ajuste é porque os valores são válidos, senão é um indicativo de que algum valor é inválido (pode ser dia 31 em meses que só tem 30 dias, ou 29 de fevereiro em um ano não-bissexto, etc).

---

Se quer usar outros separadores além da barra (como `-` ou `.`), a regex muda um pouco:

```js
let match = /^(\d{2})([-\/.]?)(\d{2})\2(\d{4})$/.exec('20.10.2018');
if (match) {
    let dia = parseInt(match[1]);
    let mes = parseInt(match[3]);
    let ano = parseInt(match[4]);

    let d = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia);
    let dataValida = d.getFullYear() == ano
                     && d.getMonth() + 1 == mes
                     && d.getDate() == dia;
    console.log(dataValida); // true
} else {
    console.log('string não está no formato dd/mm/aaaa, ou não é uma data');
}
```

Agora eu coloquei outro grupo de captura para o separador: `([-\/.]?)`. O trecho `[-\/.]` significa "um hífen, **ou** uma barra, **ou** um ponto", e o `?` [torna este trecho opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

Em seguida eu uso a [referência](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\2`, que significa "a mesma string que foi capturada no grupo 2". O grupo 2 é o segundo par de parênteses, que no caso é o separador. Isso garante que o mesmo separador que foi usado entre o dia e o mês estará entre o mês e o ano. E como ele é opcional, caso não haja separador, o `\2` será a string vazia, garantindo que ou tem o mesmo separador, ou não tem nenhum.

Outro ponto de atenção é que, como eu incluí mais um grupo de captura (para o separador), o mês e ano agora são os grupos 3 e 4 (`match[3]` e `match[4]`).

---

#### Moment.js

Outra alternativa é usar a biblioteca [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). No caso, você pode [passar um array com os formatos possíveis](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) e em seguida usar [`isValid()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) para saber se a data é válida.

```js
let formatos = ['DD/MM/YYYY', 'DD-MM-YYYY', 'DD.MM.YYYY', 'DDMMYYYY'];

console.log(moment('29/02/2016', formatos).isValid()); // true
console.log(moment('30-04-2017', formatos).isValid()); // true
console.log(moment('31.12.2018', formatos).isValid()); // true
console.log(moment('10032019', formatos).isValid()); //true

// datas inválidas
console.log(moment('29/02/2017', formatos).isValid()); // false
console.log(moment('31-04-2017', formatos).isValid()); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

Se quer **mesmo** prosseguir com a regex gigante, você pode retirar o `?` depois dos zeros, pois assim eles deixam de ser opcionais (com o zero opcional a regex aceita `04` e `4`).

Eu também troquei os separadores por `[-\/.]?` para deixá-los opcionais. A sua regex usa `\/|-|\.` (uma barra **ou** hífen **ou** ponto), mas quando temos várias opções com apenas um caractere cada, é mais fácil usar os [colchetes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Colocando o `?` depois torna o trecho opcional, e pelo que vi a regex usa a mesma coisa que fiz no segundo exemplo acima, usando `\1`, `\2`, etc para que o separador seja o mesmo.

Por fim, removi o `?` depois dos dois primeiros dígitos do ano, pois assim a regex exigirá anos com somente 4 dígitos:

`^(?:(?:31([-\/.]?)(?:0[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)([-\/.]?)(?:0[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$|^(?:29([-\/.]?)02\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))))$|^(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])([-\/.]?)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$`

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/bXWUPM/4/) alguns exemplos dela funcionando. Segue abaixo alguns testes também:

```js
let r = /^(?:(?:31([-\/.]?)(?:0[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)([-\/.]?)(?:0[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$|^(?:29([-\/.]?)02\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))))$|^(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])([-\/.]?)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$/;

console.log(r.test('29/02/2016')); // true
console.log(r.test('30-04-2019')); // true
console.log(r.test('20.12.2018')); // true
console.log(r.test('15032019')); // true


console.log(r.test('10-10/2018')); // false
console.log(r.test('29/02/2017')); // false
console.log(r.test('31/04/2018')); // false
console.log(r.test('32/01/2019')); // false
```

Comment: Sem dúvidas, o [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) mata de letra quando o assunto se trata de **regex**.

Comment: sem dúvidas incrivel explicação, e a sua função realmente é ótima, o problema é que preciso mesmo da Regex por não poder utilizar javascript, só posso usar regex mesmo

Comment: @flourigh Atualizei a resposta com uma alternativa, veja se é o que vc precisa

Comment: @flourigh se não pode usar JS, poderia retirar da pergunta a tag [tag:javascript]

Comment: é que o local utiliza javascript, eu é que não posso enviar javascript, posso colocar um regex no local indicado que é todo feito em javascript, ou vuejs

Comment: @AndréFilipe o cara é gênio demais, além de explicar detalhadamente, fez a coisa funcionar de forma perfeita, não resolveu o problema, ensinou a resolver mostrando os erros, cara, entendi mais coisa nesta resposta do que em vários manuais

Comment: @flourigh A maioria dos "manuais" de regex é meio ruim mesmo, pois só explicam a sintaxe, mas não como usar. Mas tem sites bons também, eu gosto bastante [desse](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) e [desse](https://www.rexegg.com). E livros, eu recomendo [esse](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) e [esse](https://www.amazon.com/Regular-Expressions-Cookbook-Solutions-Programming/dp/1449319432) :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo muito obrigado por ajudar também com as referencias para estudo, irá me ajudar bastante mesmo pois preciso fazer várias validações com regex, agora vou partir para a validação de CPF, tenho qm javascript mas também precisará ser em regex, espero um dia poder ajudar como me ajudou

Answer (score 0):

Cara, não entendi muito bem tua pergunta, mas... Acredito que essa Regex resolva seu problema:

`\d{2}[-\/\.]\d{2}[-\/\.]\d{4}|\d{8}`

Ela aceita formatos de data como (acredito que foi o que tu pediu né?):
dd/mm/yyyy
dd.mm.yyyy
dd-mm-yyyy
ddmmyyyy

Comment: realmente, é isso mesmo, mas preciso saber se o ano é bissexto também, no caso da sua ele só valida quantidade, no caso, preciso das verificações que estão contidas no exemplo que dei, que verifica ano, dia do mês entre outras palavras, se a data existe mesmo

Comment: O problema é que essa regex também aceita separadores misturados, como `23/01-2019` ou `23-01.2019`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/WELJ0B/1/)

Comment: @hkotsubo neste caso, dá para utilizarmos os retrovisores de regex, ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:
[link](https://regex101.com/r/cRGVvH/1)

Porém, para o que foi questionado eu não indico a utilização de regex porque a data precisa ser validada quando levamos em consideração os meses que tem 28, 30, 31 dias (fora os anos bisextos)...

Comment: @A.Chiele Sim, concordo 100% com vc (regex não é a melhor solução pra esse problema), e a solução que vc sugeriu eu já tinha colocado na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/371327/112052) :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo realmente a sua expressão é boa e não permite ano com 2 caracteres e testei com ano bissexto 29/02/2016 e funcionou, anulando o 2015 por exemplo, no caso não entendi ao certo, sua expressão não calcula estas datas? "porque a data precisa ser validada quando levamos em consideração os meses que tem 28, 30, 31 dias (fora os anos bisextos)", porém achei um erro no Mês, ele não valida 10|11|12 apenas de 01-09 ou 1-9 não validando os com inicio 1 (out, nov, dez)

Comment: @flourigh Se está falando da regex gigante, ela usa várias alternâncias (`|`), ou seja, várias possibilidades (dia x e mês y com ano z **ou** dia a, mês b e ano c **ou**, etc). Ela testa várias possibilidades fazendo com que 29/02 só seja aceito em anos bissextos, etc. Mas **a regex não faz contas** (ela não divide o ano por 4 pra saber se é bissexto, por exemplo), o que ela faz é testar várias opções para que no final os valores sejam somente os esperados (por isso ela fica tão grande)

Comment: @flourigh Na minha resposta eu adicionei uns testes no final e veja que testei com 20.12.2018 e funcionou. Se puder editar sua pergunta colocando exatamente os testes que falham, posso dar uma olhada

Comment: @hkotsubo eu não entendi direito, a primeira vez que cliquei neste link https://regex101.com/r/cRGVvH/1 a data 29/02/2015 não funcionou, como comentei, mas agora funcionou, que esquisito, eu entendo as informações sobre tamanho e conta e tudo o que mencionaram sobre a regex gigante, a que coloquei no exemplo, funciona com ano bissexto e invalida meses sem 31 dias, só queria mesmo saber onde invalido a quantidade de caracteres para DD(2)/MM(2)/AAAA(4) para poder utilizar melhor, eu só não entendi esta parte dela

Comment: @flourigh Esta regex que vc passou (https://regex101.com/r/cRGVvH/1) só verifica se o dia está entre 1 e 31. As outras regras (fevereiro tem 28 ou 29 dias dependendo do ano, etc), somente a regex gigante tem. E a regex desse link aceita meses com 1 dígito por causa do `(0[1-9]|[1-9]|1[0-2])` (veja no meio tem `|[1-9]|`, que é um dígito de 1 a 9, retire isso e deixe apenas `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])` que aí vai aceitar apenas meses com 2 dígitos. Outro detalhe é que `\d{1}` é redundante, pode usar apenas `\d` que é a mesma coisa

Comment: @hkotsubo realmente, reparei depois, deve ter sido um erro meu na euforia, porém ele começou a dar erro na validação do mês quando adicionei um | neste trecho (\/|\-|\.|) para permitir nada como divisor, editei a pergunta

Comment: @flourigh Na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/371327/112052) eu coloquei uma alternativa para o `(\/|\-|\.|)` (no final dela, veja a última regex), vc chegou a testá-la?

Comment: @hkotsubo realmente, está ali mesmo, eu acho que passei direto por ele depois que vi os javascripts, vou ler direito, de fato, funcionou mesmo https://regex101.com/r/afx8f1/1/