# Como transformar string em objeto Date com TypeScript?

Tags: string, typescript, data, visual-studio-code

Estou recebendo do formulário HTML uma string contendo a data selecionada no padrão `dd/mm/yyyy`, e quero criar um objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) a partir dessa string.

O problema é que o `Date` só aceita strings nos padrões reconhecidos pelo método [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), que são os padrões **IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps** e **ISO8601**. Há ainda a opção de passar os números separadamente, seguindo os exemplos:

```
let data1 = new Date(ano,mes,dia);
let data2 = new Date(ano,mes,dia,hora,minuto,segundo);
```

O que eu preciso é uma forma prática de converter uma string no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` em uma das entradas possíveis do construtor de `Date`.

Tentei utilizar uma função que havia desenvolvido durante um curso, que quebrava a string em partes e invertia sua ordem, mas ela acusou erro no VS Code:

```
textoParaData(texto){
  if(!/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/.test(texto))
    throw new Error(`Deve estar no formato dd/mm/aaaa`);
  return new Date(...(texto.split('/').map((item, indice) => item - indice % 2).reverse())); // Expected 0-7 arguments, but got 0 or more.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode mudar a função para:

```
textoParaData(texto) {
    let m = texto.match(/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/);
    if (! m)
        throw new Error('Deve estar no formato dd/mm/aaaa');
    m = m.slice(1, 4).map(v => parseInt(v));
    return new Date(m[2], m[1] - 1, m[0]);
}
```

Agora a regex possui os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim eu garanto que a string só vai ter o que está na regex. Se eu não usar `^` e `$`, a regex pode validar strings que possuem qualquer outra coisa antes ou depois da data.

Em seguida, eu vejo se a regex encontrou algum *match*. Caso não tenha encontrado, já lanço o erro.

Repare que coloquei os números entre parênteses, pois eles formam [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que são [retornados em um array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value). Como esse array possui várias outras informações (como o texto completo da data encontrada), eu uso `slice` para obter somente os grupos (que serão respectivamente o dia, mês e ano), e uso `map` para transformá-los em números (lembre-se que uma regex sempre trabalha com texto, então `m` é um array de strings).

Depois basta criar o `Date` passando o ano, mês e dia (lembrando de subtrair um do mês, já que [no `Date` do JavaScript, janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/405994/112052), etc).

---

Esta regex ainda aceita valores inválidos, como por exemplo `31/02/2019`. No caso, como fevereiro não tem 31 dias, o dia 31 é ajustado para 3 de março. Se quiser validar os valores, uma forma é verificar se o `Date` criado possui os mesmos valores originais (pois isto indica que não foi feito nenhum desses ajustes automáticos):

```
textoParaData(texto) {
    let m = texto.match(/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/);
    if (! m)
        throw new Error('Deve estar no formato dd/mm/aaaa');
    let [dia, mes, ano] = m.slice(1, 4).map(v => parseInt(v));
    let data = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia);
    if (data.getDate() !== dia || data.getMonth() + 1 !== mes || data.getFullYear() !== ano)
        throw new Error('Valores inválidos');
    return data;
}
```

---

Até é possível mudar a regex para que ela mesma valide se os valores da data estão corretos (se o mês tem 30 ou 31 dias, se é ano bissexto, etc), mas não vale a pena, pois ela ficaria grande demais e se tornaria um pesadelo de manutenção - conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363711/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/371327/112052).